# How can I build a 12V to 24V DC-DC Converter with up to 3A of Output current to power up a motor

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I've built a 12V to 300V boost covnerter using a MAX1771, but now required one which can handle up to 3A with a 24V output. Should I attempt this task with the same chip or could someone point me in the right way to solve this problem?

EDIT: MAX1771 can only handle up to 24W of output power, seems like I'll have to find an alternate.

Comment: There are numerous possible chips available for this kind of DC-DC regulator. Check for example TI's [webench](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/overview.page?DCMP=hpa_design_center&HQS=analogdesigncenter) to select the best chip in their portfolio. Unless you provide more detailed specification, it's hard to answer precisely (e.g. type of package, etc.)

Comment: That's one neat tool, I am rather inexperienced with this sort of thing so this is extremely helpful. I'll probably settle with their TPS43060, although if I want the IC to be enable whenever power is available should I just link the EN pin to Vin?

Comment: If you look at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps43060.pdf), it's stated that EN has an internal pull-up and can be left unconnected if you want to keep the regulator enabled at all times.